# архивация логов

Tags: linux, логирование

есть каталог `/var/log`.

как с помощью с скрипта заархивировать логи старше, чем вчера, в папку `/var/log/archive`?

логи имеют формат `yyyy_mm_dd_name.log`

Comment: а в чём именно состоит трудность? в настройке logrotate?

Comment: Лучше бы уточнить, что именно должен делать скрипт.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### главные трудности, видимо, следующие:

1. отобрать только те файлы в текущем каталоге, имена которых соответствуют шаблону `yyyy_mm_dd_name.log`, где `name` — произвольный набор символов, не содержащий символа `_`
2. исключить из отобранных те файлы, в именах которых часть `yyyy_mm_dd` соответствует сегодняшней или вчерашней дате
3. что-то сделать с найденными файлами (например, переместить куда-нибудь)

---

### решение:

1. отобрать в текущем каталоге такие файлы можно, например, так:

   ```
   $ find -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-basic -regex "\./[0-9]\{4\}_[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}_[^_]\+\.log"
   ```

   проверим, создав тестовые файлы (один содержит сегодняшнюю дату, один — вчерашнюю, один — позавчерашнюю, и один, контрольный, не содержит даты в имени):

   ```
   $ touch 2016_07_04_some.log 2016_07_03_some.log 2016_07_02_some.log some.file
   $ find -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-basic -regex "\./[0-9]\{4\}_[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}_[^_]\+\.log"
   ./2016_07_03_some.log
   ./2016_07_04_some.log
   ./2016_07_02_some.log
   ```

   вроде, правильно.
2. чтобы исключить файлы, в имени которых содержится сегодняшняя или вчерашняя дата, надо добавить к опциям программы *find* такую примерно конструкцию:

   ```
   \! -regex "\./2016_07_04_[^_]\+\.log" \! -regex "\./2016_07_03_[^_]\+\.log"
   ```

   тогда в вывод попадает только позавчерашний файл:

   ```
   ./2016_07_02_some.log
   ```

   но завтра ведь даты будут другие. как привязаться к **текущему** дню?

   с помощью программы *date*, например. сегодняшняя дата:

   ```
   $ date +'%Y_%m_%d'
   2016_07_04
   ```

   и вчерашняя:

   ```
   $ date -d 'day ago' +'%Y_%m_%d'
   2016_07_03
   ```

   заключаем вызовы *date* в «операторные скобки» `$(...)`, подставляем в нужные места, и получаем длинную команду:

   ```
   $ find -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-basic -regex "\./[0-9]\{4\}_[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}_[^_]\+\.log" \! -regex "\./$(date +'%Y_%m_%d')_[^_]\+\.log" \! -regex "\./$(date -d 'day ago' +'%Y_%m_%d')_[^_]\+\.log"
   ./2016_07_02_some.log
   ```
3. для того, чтобы переместить найденные программой *find* файлы в каталог, например, `/var/log/archive`, можно добавить к опциям той же программы такую, например, конструкцию:

   ```
   -exec mv {} /var/log/archive \;
   ```

---

### итого полный текст команды будет таким:

```
$ find -maxdepth 1 -regextype posix-basic \
 -regex "\./[0-9]\{4\}_[0-9]\{2\}_[0-9]\{2\}_[^_]\+\.log" \
 \! -regex "\./$(date +'%Y_%m_%d')_[^_]\+\.log" \
 \! -regex "\./$(date -d 'day ago' +'%Y_%m_%d')_[^_]\+\.log" \
 -exec mv {} /var/log/archive \;
```

он разбит на строки исключительно для удобства обзора. если вставлять этот текст в одну строку, то последний в каждой строке символ `\` надо удалить.

Comment: друг написал
https://yadi.sk/d/5YCCjag-szoe3
у вас все круто но тут еще и архивирует

Comment: Как насчет того чтобы настроить logrotate? ))

Comment: @fermeg, не архивирует, а сжимает. дополнить команду ещё одной опцией `exec` ведь несложно: `-exec gzip /var/log/archive/{} \;`

Comment: @NickVolynkin, мы не ищем лёгких путей!

Comment: @fermeg, кстати, скрипт, ссылку на который вы привели, не подходит для изложенных в вопросе требований. он просто «не найдёт» ваши файлы с именами в приведённом вами формате.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin программист должен быть ленивым )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, так я уже устал повторять, что я не программист.

Answer (score 11):

> **Не нужно писать собственное решение, когда уже есть различные готовые.**

## Автоматическая ротация и архивация логов

Решение называется [logrotate](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html).

Предположим, вы хотите ротировать и архивировать логи приложения *name*

Конфигурация в файле `/etc/logrotate.d/name`:

```bash
/var/log/*name.log {
    daily # ежедневно
    olddir /var/log/archive # перемещать в другую папку
    missingok # не создавать сообщение об ошибке, если лог пустой
}
```

Logrotate исключает необходимость приложению самостоятельно записывать дату в имя файла. Приложение может писать логи в один и тот же файл, который в момент ротации будет заменяться на новый. Если приложение самостоятельно не переоткрывает файл при записи каждой новой строки, то будет полезна опция `copytruncate`. С ней logrotate не пересоздает файлы логов, а вырезает содержимое и пишет его в новый файл.

```bash
/var/log/*name.log {
    ...
    copytruncate
}
```

> ```
>    copytruncate
>           Truncate  the  original log file in place after creating a copy,
>           instead of moving the old log file and optionally creating a new
>           one,  It  can be used when some program can not be told to close
>           its logfile and thus might continue writing (appending)  to  the
>           previous log file forever.
> ```

Если по соображениям места на диске или полезности вы хотите хранить логи за последние N периодов ротации, то добавьте опцию `rotate N`. Например, за последнюю неделю:

```bash
/var/log/*name.log {
    ...
    daily
    rotate 7
}
```

---

## Централизованное хранение логов.

Хранить важные логи прямо на хосте - это плохо, и вот почему:

1. Там может быть недостаточно места. У меня был случай, когда логи заняли всё место и парализовали хост (к счастью, тестовый).
2. Если всё совсем сломается, то логи будут очень нужны, а вы на них не посмотрите.
3. Читать логи в текстовом редакторе или анализировать grep'ом - неэффективно.
4. У этого способа масштабируемость хуже линейной. То есть чтобы следить за логами на вдвое большем количестве хостов вам понадобится более чем вдвое больше ресурсов (человекочасов и т.п.).

Логи должны храниться централизованно и в базе данных. Тогда:

1. Вы можете получать оперативную аналитику
2. Вы можете легко сравнивать логи между разными хостами, приложениями, периодами времени
3. В случае поломки все или почти все логи будут вам доступны
4. Масштабируемость примерно логарифмическая.

Есть ряд решений, одно из них - стек ELK (Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana).

Возможно, в данный момент для ваших задач достаточно простой ротации. Но, пожалуйста, ориентируйтесь на централизованное хранение.